# Parse Push on WP 8.1

Tags: windows, cordova, parse-platform, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using ionic/cordova to build an app and I've chosen Parse to handle Push Notifications. It works well on iOS and Anrdoid, but it won't work on WP 8.1.

I know 8.1 is not officially supported by Parse. Is there anyway I could still use it? Like with an C# plugin I could write myself?

Are there any other push services I could use for WP 8.1? Probably with a REST API?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Parse but you said a REST API would be fine. In this case the easiest approach would be an Azure Mobile Service. Depending on the number of push notifications Mobile Services and Notifications Hubs are even free.

Here is what you have to do:

- Create a free Azure Account
- Create a Mobile Service (I am using .Net but you can also use JavaScript for the "backend")
- Open your Mobile Service in Visual Studio and create a new "custom api". Here is a step by step tutorial on how to do this: [CustomAPIs - Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-define-custom-api/)
- You now have a REST API that you can call form your server.
- To send your push notification just use something along the lines of this in your custom api and you are ready to go [Add push notifications - Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-universal-dotnet-get-started-push/):

`var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("YOUR_NOTIFICATIONHUB_ENDPOINT", "YOUR_NOTIFICATIONHUB_NAME");`

```
notification = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" +
           @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01"">" +
           @"<text id=""1>YOUR TEXT</text>" +
           @"</binding></visual></toast>";

await hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(notification, tags);
```

With `tags` you can specify who receives the notifications. Use the tags as UserIds to send targeted notifications.

Answer (score 0):

The push service I use for WP 8.1 (and iOS and Android too) is Azure mobile services.  Their push notification hub makes it really simple on the backend to support all three platforms without issue.  On the client side they have an Azure plugin that uses the existing Phonegap Push plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
I know 8.1 is not officially supported by Parse. Is there anyway I could still use it? Like with an C# plugin I could write myself?
```

You can just include WinRT libraries in Windows Phone 8.1 project. It's works perfectly!